# Start Vim in insert mode for new files

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, insert-mode

I mostly use Vim to edit configuration files so I understand why it starts in **normal mode**. But I also use *vi mode* for the REPL (bash, zsh, ipython, etc.) and the shell always starts in **insert mode** (this makes sense because you just want to start typing a command).

For the same reason, when I open a new empty file `vim foo.txt`, I want to be in insert mode. So I'm looking for a *vimrc* function that checks if the file is empty and then put me in insert mode.

In this way I can be consistent across the terminal. When there aren't text objects I know I'm in insert mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add this to your vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile * startinsert
```

The autocommand creates a command which is executed on a specific event.

Here the event is `BufNewFile` the doc descibes it has:

> When starting to edit a file that doesn't
>                 exist.  Can be used to read in a skeleton
>                 file.

The `*` is here to execute the command on every new file (not a specific filetype or name)

And the command to be executed is `startinsert` which starts insert mode.

Note that it will also work for new files edited from vim with `e foo.txt` for example.

See:

- [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd%2devents)
- [`:h BufNewFile`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufNewFile)
- [`:h :startinsert`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#%3astartinsert)

Comment: Anyway, when the background is set (ex. `set background=dark`) in the `.vimrc` it opens the new file in insert mode with `-- INSERT --` in the first line.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related?

Comment: I try to explain: only when I have both `autocmd BufNewFile * startinsert` and `set background=dark` in my `.vimrc` if I open a new file `vim foo.txt`, the text `-- INSERT --` will appear in the first line, so I had to remove `set background=dark` from my `.vimrc`.

Comment: @isar I'm sure there's another reason. Do you set the background before or after the autocmd?

Comment: @isar the `background` option shouldn't have an impact on that, have a look at [this really good question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) to debug that :)

Comment: @isar Is it actually present in the file, or just on the screen? i.e. does it go away if you e.g. exit insert mode and press ctrl-l?

Comment: @Random832 yes, it does go away if I press `Esc` and then `Ctrl`+`l`. So it is actually on the screen. If I start typing it also goes away progressively and get overridden from the characters I insert. Thank you

Comment: @isar There's probably something wrong with your `term` or termcap settings. You should open another question for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`vim -c 'startinsert'`

Will start Vim in insert mode pass it a file and it will open that file in insert mode.

The easiest way is to make save this as an alias in your terminal config.

Example:
`alias vim="vim -c 'startinsert' "`

Comment: This works! I'm using this in double commander for using gvim as external editor